# Need to execute a shell script from java

Tags: java, shell

I need to execute(run) a shell script which resides in the server(Solaris) from java. Please help me how to execute a file from java.? I have tried with sendCommand() of TelnetToClient. So please help me in running a file from my GUI.

The program goes like this.

```
TelnetToPort tele = new TelnetToPort("opmer3");
tele.login("root","root");
String command_ = "/usr/bin/bash /opt/nrl/logs/applications/ns/lccommands.sh";
tele.runComm(command_);
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  What errors do you get?  Also, what is `TelnetToPort`? Is this something you wrote, or a package you downloaded?

Comment: Have you tried the `-c` option: `...bash -c /opt/nrl/...`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for optimized solution for executing any scripts for your java class, then you can use Jsch with Google Expect4j libraries.

For jsch, go to http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/
For Expect4j, go to http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/

Following is small code sample for log in and executing file fro remote java class.

```
private Expect4j SSH(String hostname, String username,String password, int port) throws Exception {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
    if (password != null) {         
        session.setPassword(password);
    }
    Hashtable<String,String> config = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect(60000);
    channel = (ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell");
    Expect4j expect = new Expect4j(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getOutputStream());
    channel.connect();      
    return expect;
}
```

This method will open up SSH stream to remote server which will be used by expect4j for sending commands.

```
private boolean executeCommands() {
        boolean isSuccess = true;
        Closure closure = new Closure() {
            public void run(ExpectState expectState) throws Exception {
                buffer.append(expectState.getBuffer());             
                expectState.exp_continue();
            }
        };
        List<Match> lstPattern =  new ArrayList<Match>();
        String[] regEx = SSHConstants.linuxPromptRegEx;  
        if (regEx != null && regEx.length > 0) {
            synchronized (regEx) {
                for (String regexElement : regEx) {//list of regx like,  :>, /> etc. it is possible command prompts of your remote machine
                    try {
                        RegExpMatch mat = new RegExpMatch(regexElement, closure);
                        lstPattern.add(mat);                        
                    } catch (MalformedPatternException e) {                     
                        return false;
                    } catch(Exception e) {                      
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                lstPattern.add(new EofMatch( new Closure() { // should cause entire page to be collected
                    public void run(ExpectState state) {
                    }
                }));
                lstPattern.add(new TimeoutMatch(defaultTimeOut, new Closure() {
                    public void run(ExpectState state) {
                    }
                }));
            }
        }
        try {
            Expect4j expect = SSH(objConfig.getHostAddress(), objConfig.getUserName(), objConfig.getPassword(), SSHConstants.SSH_PORT);
            expect.setDefaultTimeout(defaultTimeOut);       
            if(isSuccess) {
                for(String strCmd : lstCmds)
                    isSuccess = isSuccess(lstPattern,strCmd);
            }
            boolean isFailed = checkResult(expect.expect(lstPattern));
            return !isFailed;
        } catch (Exception ex) {            
            return false;
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }


private boolean isSuccess(List<Match> objPattern,String strCommandPattern) {
        try {   
            boolean isFailed = checkResult(expect.expect(objPattern));

            if (!isFailed) {
                expect.send(strCommandPattern);         
                expect.send("\r");              
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        } catch (MalformedPatternException ex) {    
            return false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ProcessBuilder("ssh", "root@opmer3", command_).start();
```